# How firebase order documents in database (cloud firestore)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

How firebase order to docs???, i said that because the docs have a special comportament and idk why.Thx

See to know what i mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a little filter icon at the top of that document list:

[image]

If you click that, you'll get the option to sort the document list on any fields.

Comment: thx for answer and edit <3, but what i was meaning is the system, how the doc by default will be ordered by google, i think was by alphabetical order but why a P is between two A by default. Is a bug?

Comment: I think the default sort order is indeed by document ID, so I'm not sure how the `PlayerUnknown` document ended up in the middle of the others. Did you rename it by any change? If not, does it stay in the same place when you reload?

Comment: this is the id for docs is from `await firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(title).set(post);` /// yes i reload the page and the same too